# MySQL PDO: could not find driver - on one virtual host only

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

I frankly don't know where to start solving this one...

My dev environment is on OSX (10.8.5 if that matters).  I'm running apache web server, php and mysql database locally. From PHP I'm connecting to MySQL using PDO - and everything works fine.

In my `/etc/hosts` I have this line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost dev.local
```

My apache is configured with virtual hosts `localhost` and `dev.local` in such a way that if I put `http://dev.local` in the browser, I access code from DocumentRoot `/var/www/dev.local` and if I access it in any other way (e.g. put 127.0.0.1 in the browser), I access code from DocumentRoot `/var/www/localhost`.

Now I need to be able to test the app from another device (ipad, as the client wants the app to run on ipad).  I've changed my apache config so that the default access is to the `/var/www/dev.local` DocumentRoot.  Now, whether I put `http://dev.local` or `http://localhost` into the address bar, I get to the same code.  And here's where the issue starts.

As I mentioned above, I use PDO from PHP to connect to MySQL.  If I put `http://dev.local` into the browser address bar, then everything works correctly.  If, however, I access my app as `http://localhost` or from another device, I receive error message `could not find driver`.  This is the most bizarre thing, as I'm accessing the same code base and get an error one way but don't get it in another way.

I do have PDO enabled and drivers installed correctly.  If I access my app with `http://localhost`, I *do* have `pdo_mysql` in my phpinfo, therefore the driver is installed correctly.

Any ideas where to start investigating is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has the iPad been granted permissions to access `localhost` on your network? That's all I can think of, including the router.

Comment: i think in the Ipad you have to put the dev server IP...localhost has an special meaning unless you have a special configuration, I dont know on mac  where can be, but in windows you have to edit the host file to point any alias in the net, the same with centos...my though

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not even using the ipad yet.  On the dev machine, `dev.local` works fine, but `127.0.0.1` does not.

Comment: @EmilioGort I'm not even using the ipad yet. On the dev machine, dev.local works fine, but 127.0.0.1 does not.

Comment: What is the DSN that you're using?

Comment: from my experience with wamp, when I wrote 127.0.0.1 from the same machine I got Permission Denied...until I grant access for outside in httpd.conf file

Comment: @eggyal And the winner is... _eggyal_.  I went to check the DSN - it's quite a complicated `config.php`, which builds the DSN based on some various parameters.  And at the end of it, if it didn't match any predefined setup, it was setting all parts of the DSN to empty string, including the driver - no wonder it couldn't find it!

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`